# How to make only 1 role able to run a /command on discord.js v14

Tags: discord, discord.js

I just need it so only a role can use a slash command, as i’m trying to make an embed builder and i don’t want my entire server to use make embeds

I haven’t tried anything as i am very new to the whole thing, but i have a small idea on how to do it.

(it isn’t a need but i’d be cool if you could assign it with a command)

Comment: You can use the [setDefaultMemberPermissions()](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/ApplicationCommand:Class#setDefaultMemberPermissions) function when creating your command to set the permission a user needs to run the command